How can I show an empty badge when a push notification is received on iOS?
We have an ask to show an empty badge on our iOS app icon when a push notification is received.
From what I understand, setting the badge count to -1 will show an empty badge (however this tidbit is from other posts; I couldn't find it in the official documentation).
We are already using an SDK that has a drop-in Notification Service extension.  What we've tried:

Catch the request object in didReceiveNotificationRequest (before its sent to the SDK's Notification Service... or so we think?).  Copy the content from the request object, updated the badge value, create a new request object with the original objects identifier and trigger and the new content, and send that to the Notification Service.
This crashes the notification service, resulting in a rich push being delivered as a standard push with no image.

@implementation NotificationService
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.baseExtension = [[ITBNotificationServiceExtension alloc] init];

    UNMutableNotificationContent *requestWithBadgeCount = request.mutableCopy;
    NSNumber *emptyBadgeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
    requestWithBadgeCount.badge = emptyBadgeCount;
    UNNotificationRequest *updatedRequest = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:request.identifier content:requestWithBadgeCount trigger:request.trigger];

    [self.baseExtension didReceiveNotificationRequest:updatedRequest withContentHandler:contentHandler];
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    [self.baseExtension serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire];
}
@end


Patch the SDK's Notification Service by updating the bestAttempCount.badge.  This has not affect, but didn't crash the service.
Patch the SDK's Notification Service by calling UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount() (wrapped in a guard for iOS 16+).  This works, but only with positive integer.  Setting -1 had no effect.

Are we barking up the wrong tree here?

AFAIK apps csn only be badged with a number. You can't have an empty badge

The concept of an 'Empty Badge' does not exist in iOS.
Though, setting the badge's value to 0 will ensure that no badge is shown.
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "title": "Notification Title",
        "body": "Notification Body"
    },
    "badge": 0
}

}

Thank you! Do you know if it used to? I’m trying to track down when the support for -1 was dropped.
